# Second connection to server socket refused in android

Tags: android, sockets

I have a client/server socket program for android working through Direct WIFI connection.It includes several Request and Response between client and server phone. My code works perfectly for the first time but in second time client gets "Connection refused" and server "socket closed" error message.in third time it works again and in fourth time raise that errors and ....
Could anyone help me about this issue?
this is server code:

```
new Thread(){
            public void run(){                
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
                try {
                    //Create a socket and listen to that
                    try {
                        if(welcomeSocket == null)
                            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(COMMUNICATION_PORT);
                    }catch(Exception qwe){
                        Log.d("Info", "qwe:" + qwe.getMessage());
                    }
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i == 0) {

                        try {
                            //Waiting for client connection
                            socket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                        }catch(Exception qwe2){
                            Log.d("Info", "qwe2:" + qwe2.getMessage());
                        }
                        //i++;

                        new Thread(){
                            public void run(){
                                try {
                                    InputStream is;
                                    DataInputStream dIn;
                                    OutputStream os;
                                    DataOutputStream dOut;
                                    //socket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                                    log("Connection accepted");
                                    //Create an input stream for receiving data from server
                                    is = socket.getInputStream();
                                    dIn = new DataInputStream(is);
                                    //Get an output stream for sending data to server phone
                                    os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                    dOut = new DataOutputStream(os);

                                    boolean done = false;
                                    byte messageType;
                                    String message;
                                    int serverReplyType = 0;
                                    String serverReply = "NOP";

                                    while (!done) {
                                        messageType = dIn.readByte();
                                        message = dIn.readUTF();

                                        Log.d("Info", "Received: " + messageType);
                                        Log.d("Info", "Received: " + message);

                                        switch (messageType) {
                                            //----------------------------------------
                                            //Comparing Job ID and Location ID of client phone and server phone
                                            case JOB_ID_CHECK_REQ:
                                                String[] tokens = message.split("#");
                                                serverReplyType = JOB_ID_CHECK_RESP;
                                                if (Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) == currentJob.getJobId() && Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) == currentJob.getJobLocationId()) {
                                                    serverReply = "ACCEPTED";
                                                    log("Syncing data verified");
                                                } else {
                                                    serverReply = "ID MISMATCH";
                                                    done = true;
                                                    log("It is not possible to sync none equal Jobs.");
                                                    log("Please select same Job in both phone.");
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            //----------------------------------------
                                            //Generating JSON string including Racks data
                                            case RACK_LIST_REQ:
                                                log("Sending Racks' data");
                                                serverReplyType = RACK_LIST_RESP;
                                                serverReply = racks.size() > 0 ? (new Gson()).toJson(racks) : "NOP";
                                                break;
                                            //----------------------------------------
                                            //Inserting new Racks to local Db
                                            case NEW_RACK_FOR_INSERT:
                                                log("Receiving new Racks' data for insert");
                                                if (!message.equals("NOP")) {
                                                    List<Rack> diffRacks = new Gson().fromJson(message, new TypeToken<List<Rack>>() {
                                                    }.getType());
                                                    rackDataSource rds = new rackDataSource(CrossPhoneSync.this);
                                                    rds.open();
                                                    rds.crossPhoneSync_InsertDiff(diffRacks);
                                                    rds.close();
                                                }
                                                serverReplyType = DONE;
                                                serverReply = "NOP";
                                                done = true;
                                                break;
                                            //----------------------------------------
                                            case DONE:
                                                done = true;
                                                log("Done");
                                                break;
                                        }

                                        Log.d("Info", "Send: " + serverReplyType);
                                        Log.d("Info", "Send: " + serverReply);
                                        dOut.writeByte(serverReplyType);
                                        dOut.writeUTF(serverReply);
                                        dOut.flush();
                                    }
                                    log("Operation completed!");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    log("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                    Log.d("Info", "ServerPhoneError:" + e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } finally {
                                    //Close stream and socket
                                    //closeSocket(true);
                                    Disconnect(null);
                                }
                                log("Done!");
                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                }catch(Exception qw){
                    Log.d("Info", "Eq1:" + qw.getMessage());
                }finally {
                    try {
                        if (welcomeSocket != null) {
                            welcomeSocket.close();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Info", "Close_ServerSocket@: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

and client code:

```
Socket socket2 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream is;
                    DataInputStream dIn;
                    OutputStream os;
                    DataOutputStream dOut;
                    //Create a socket for connecting to server phone
                    socket2 = new Socket(host, COMMUNICATION_PORT);
                    //socket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                    //Get an output stream for sending data to server phone
                    os = socket2.getOutputStream();
                    dOut = new DataOutputStream(os);
                    //Create an input stream for receiving data from server
                    is = socket2.getInputStream();
                    dIn = new DataInputStream(is);

                    //Send first message
                    log("Sending verification data...");
                    int clientMessageType = JOB_ID_CHECK_REQ;
                    String clientMessageToSend = currentJob.getJobId() + "#" + currentJob.getJobLocationId();
                    dOut.writeByte(clientMessageType);
                    dOut.writeUTF(clientMessageToSend);
                    dOut.flush();

                    byte messageType;
                    String message;
                    boolean done = false;

                    while(!done) {
                        messageType = dIn.readByte();
                        message = dIn.readUTF();

                        Log.d("Info", "" + messageType);
                        Log.d("Info", message);

                        switch(messageType)
                        {
                            //----------------------------------------
                            //Sending current Job ID and Location ID to server phone for equality checking
                            case JOB_ID_CHECK_RESP:
                                if(message.equals("ACCEPTED")){
                                    log("Data verified");
                                    clientMessageType = RACK_LIST_REQ;
                                    clientMessageToSend = "NOP";
                                    log("Requesting for other phone's Racks data");
                                }else{
                                    done = true;
                                    log("It is not possible to sync none equal Jobs.");
                                    log("Please select same Job in both phone.");
                                }
                                break;
                            //----------------------------------------
                            //Comparing...
                            case RACK_LIST_RESP:
                                log("Comparing Racks' data of two phones");
                                List<Rack> serverPhoneRacks;
                                if(!message.equals("NOP"))
                                    serverPhoneRacks = new Gson().fromJson(message, new TypeToken<List<Rack>>() { }.getType());
                                else
                                    serverPhoneRacks = new ArrayList<>();
                                rackDataSource rds = new rackDataSource(CrossPhoneSync.this);
                                rds.open();
                                List<Rack> diffRacks = rds.crossPhoneSync_Compare(racks,serverPhoneRacks);
                                rds.close();

                                clientMessageType = NEW_RACK_FOR_INSERT;
                                clientMessageToSend = diffRacks == null ? "NOP" : (new Gson()).toJson(diffRacks);
                                log("Sending new Racks' data for inserting on the other phone");

                                break;
                            //----------------------------------------
                            case DONE:
                                done = true;
                                log("Done!");
                                break;
                        }

                        if(!done) {
                            dOut.writeByte(clientMessageType);
                            dOut.writeUTF(clientMessageToSend);
                            dOut.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    log("Operation completed!");
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    log("Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Info", " ClientPhoneError:" + e.getMessage());
                }finally {
                    //Close stream and socket
                    //closeSocket(false);
                    try {
                        if (socket2 != null) {
                            //socket.shutdownInput();
                            //socket.shutdownOutput();
                            socket2.close();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Info", "Close_Socket_Error5: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                log("Finished!");
```